# OpenCV CrossCompile for RaspBerry PI

Tags: linux, opencv, floating-point, arm

I have cross compiled opencv Ver 2.4.11 for Raspberry ARM BCM2708 ARMv6 using a crosstools generated toolchain. Everything works fine when I run my program on the RaspBerry (it is a face detection example).

Unfortunately execution is very slow so I would like to enable VFP tu use hw floating port support for ARMv6. I have rebuilt the toolchain using softfp (but also hardfp - nothing change) and I have recompiled opencv enabling VFPV3 support. Unfortunately RaspBerry is equipped with ARMv6 processor that seems to be not compatible with VFPV3 (it throw illegal instruction when execute code built with VFPV3 support).

So I would like to enable VFP support that should be supported by RaspBerry processor. I am not able to run cmake script of opencv to enable VFP support. It works only with neon or vfpv3 switch. So i tried to generate the makefiles with vfpv3 and then with sed to substitute vfpv3 with vfp. But when i run make the configure process start again loosing all modifications introduced with sed. How can I force cmake to use `mfpu=vfp` instead of `mfpu=vfpv3` ?

I run cmake with:

```
cmake -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/armct.cmake ..
```

and and example of the sed script is:

```
find . -name "*.make" -type f -exec sed -i 's/mfpu=vfpv3/mfpu=vfp/g' {} +
```

Comment: Please elaborate the problems you run into. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: 'How do I compile X for Y' questions aren't really what SO is for.